# How to read zipped xml from file stream

Tags: c#, xml, filestream, xmlreader, gzipstream

i've some data to store in an xml file. Easy story! To make it unreadable i've zipped it. This should work fine! But i cant't read the xml content back!

Code i used to write:

```
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( filepath, FileMode.Create ) ) {
    using( GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream( fileStream , CompressionMode.Compress ) ) {
        using( XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create( zipStream, new XmlWriterSettings() { 
            Indent = true, 
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, 
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }
            ) ) {
                xmlWriter.WriteString( xmlDocument.OuterXml );
        }
    }
}
```

Code i use to read so far:

```
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( filepath, FileMode.Open ) )
{
    using( GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream( fileStream , CompressionMode.Decompress ) )
    {
        using( XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create( zipStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment } ) )
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

The xml file looks quite simple:

```
<data>
    <name>bill</name>
    <age>45</age>
</data>
<data>
    <name>john</name>
    <age>32</age>
</data>
<data>
    <name>bill</name>
    <age>68</age>
</data>
```

i'd like to use

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName( "data" );
```

What am i missing? Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your read logic
replace

```
xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```

with

```
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlReader.ReadContentAsString());
```

This worked for me

Comment: [thumbs up](http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7ia/o5r/7iao5rp6T.jpeg) - i think i was in that tunnel while working ... thank you!